# I want to separate the back-end and front-end, and make them comunicate using HTTP msgs. What technologies could help me accomplish that?

Tags: javascript, http, scala, backbone.js

I worked with Java and Wicket for about a year and i dont like the idea of tying server and front side directly (slow, not flexible). 
I want to separate the backend and frontend, and make them comunicate using HTTP. So i want to start a new project with this idea on mind, and i wonder what tools could help me (Backbone.js?) accomplish that? and what server language can talk http/json fluently (Scala,  grovvy, Rails, Node.js...) and have a high performance.

Answer (score 1):

Akka plus Camel could provide what you want very nicely. See the documentation here http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.1/modules/camel.html

Scala is wonderfully terse for most things compared with Java. As for JSON handling there is a Scala-Json found here https://github.com/stevej/scala-json

The following is an excerpt from the akka-camel documentation.

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.camel.{Message, Consumer}

class Consumer2 extends Actor with Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "jetty:http://localhost:8877/camel/default"

  def receive = {
    case msg: Message => self.reply("Hello %s" format msg.bodyAs[String])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Blue Eyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes) is targeted at use cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lift and its [rest support](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/REST_Web_Services)

And then any javascript library.

Lift also has an excellent json library. [lift json](https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json)